# Errors in cognos schedule by trigger

Tags: java, cognos, cognos-10

I set one of my entry for schedule by trigger to save report in cognos.
I was trying to run from command line with the trigger.bat but it keeps showing up errors like this. It keeps showing the certpath not trusted and login failure.
I can’t seem to fix the errors, any suggestions?

Errors shown:

```
C:\Program Files\ibm\cognos\c10_64\webapps\utilities\trigger>trigger.bat "https:
//182.196.182.155/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognos.cgi" user1 password ladp "te
st_trigger"
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX pa
th building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBui
lderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=cn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeExcept
ion: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPat
hBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; in
ternal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=cn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:44)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:508)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:148)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:68)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:31)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:115)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.t(ab.java:364)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:175)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:592)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:275)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:541)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:89)
        at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFac
tory.java:210)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:1
91)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.ja
va:404)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)

        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrateg
y.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.ContentManagerServiceStub.logon
(ContentManagerServiceStub.java:7948)
        at Trigger.login(Trigger.java:111)
        at Trigger.main(Trigger.java:264)
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.C
ertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPat
h.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=cn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:39)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:76)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:21)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:101)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:56)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.checkServerTrusted(yc.java:77)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:281)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl
could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=Bankcommuat-CA, DC=bankcomm, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPat
hBuilderImpl.java:410)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:256)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:58)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued
 by CN=cn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.&lt;init&gt;(BasicChecker.java:111
)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCe
rtPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPat
hBuilderImpl.java:737)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertP
athBuilderImpl.java:649)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertP
athBuilderImpl.java:595)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPat
hBuilderImpl.java:356)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining e
rror
        at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:316)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.&lt;init&gt;(BasicChecker.java:108
)
        ... 36 more

        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:UAT136210

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building fa
iled: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could
 not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=Bankcommuat-CA, DC=bankcomm, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)

        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrateg
y.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.ContentManagerServiceStub.logon
(ContentManagerServiceStub.java:7948)
        at Trigger.login(Trigger.java:111)
        at Trigger.main(Trigger.java:264)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path
building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilde
rImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=cn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:44)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:508)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:148)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:68)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:31)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:115)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.t(ab.java:364)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:175)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:592)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:275)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:541)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:89)
        at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFac
tory.java:210)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:1
91)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.ja
va:404)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)

        ... 12 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.C
ertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPat
h.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=ccn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:39)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:76)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:21)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:101)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:56)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.checkServerTrusted(yc.java:77)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:281)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl
could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by
 CN=ccn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPat
hBuilderImpl.java:410)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:256)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:58)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued
 by CN=ccn-uat, DC=dcuat, DC=uat is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining erro
r
        at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCe
rtPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPat
hBuilderImpl.java:737)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertP
athBuilderImpl.java:649)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertP
athBuilderImpl.java:595)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPat
hBuilderImpl.java:356)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining e
rror
        at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:316)
        at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
        ... 36 more
Error: Login Failure - please try again.


Command Line Parameters:

<URL> [ <userName> <password> <nameSpace> ] triggerList [ <delimiter> ]

  Required arguments:

          URL - Server URL
                        eg. "http://localhost:9300/p2pd/servlet/dispatch"
  triggerList - comma separated list of trigger names
                        eg. "triggerName1,triggerName2,triggerName3"

  NOTE: If using the optional delimiter override parameter defined below, use th
e delimiter specified in that parameter to separate the trigger names
                        eg. "triggerName1|triggerName2|triggerName3"

  Optional arguments: for use with secured namespace (Anonymous disabled)

     userName - username, valid within the namespace, to run the utility
     password - password for the given user
    nameSpace - namespace for the desired user

  Optional argument:

     delimiter - Use a different triggerList delimiter character to override the
 comma delimiter if trigger names contain commas
                        eg. "|
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, you are connecting to an SSL protected URL without having the proper cert loaded into the key store.  You can either change the URL to a non SSL URL or access the dispatcher URI directly.   If that is not an option you will need to import the cert.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-triggerbat-connect-ssl-enabled-dispatcher-ibm-cognos-bi-or-replacement-ca-certificate